# Expression/ idiom meaning: "Hold your shoulders back!"

Tags: expressions, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

I was reading the poem [Father Forgets](https://faculty.sfcc.spokane.edu/InetShare/AutoWebs/kimt/father%20forgets.pdf) (pdf) by W. Livingston Larned.

> Part of the line said, "Goodbye, Daddy!"
>   
>   I frowned, and said in reply, "Hold your shoulders back!"

I couldn't find the exact meaning of this phrase.

Here's the part of the poem:

> At breakfast I found fault, too. You spilled things. You gulped down your food. You
>   put your elbows on the table. You spread butter too thick on your bread. As you started off to
>   play and I made for my train, you turned and waved a hand and called, "Goodbye, Daddy!" I
>   frowned, and said in reply, "Hold your shoulders back!"

Comment: Thanks, I already added. Please check it out if you have time.

Comment: As @Kate Bunting said in her answer. "Shoulders back" is a matter of correct posture. In the context, the expression is used to say that the father was always "correcting" the child. The poem in general is a father realizing how he has been finding fault and now repents for it. See the part "The habit of finding fault, ... I 
was measuring you by the yardstick of my own years." And ...

Comment: "It is a feeble atonement; ... Tomorrow I will be a real daddy! ...  I will bite my tongue when impatient words come. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is literal. It seems the father has been repeatedly finding fault with his child, and instead of returning the friendly "Goodbye" he criticises the child's posture. You *pull your shoulders back* when you are standing up straight. I was often admonished to do so when I was young.

Comment: https://builtwithscience.com/how-to-fix-rounded-shoulders/

Comment: It could be purely literal, but it could also have shades of the metaphorical "stand up straight" meaning to stand tall/stand proud/take things like a man, and not be weak or sad.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase

> put your shoulders back

can also be used as a metaphorical expression to encourage someone to be confident and assertive.

Source: https://www.shalanicely.com/aha-moments/shoulders-back-the-man-in-the-park/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the person who said "to put one's shoulders back" also means to be confident and assertive. This is the way we hear the phrase used in North America. One also hears "to square one's shoulders" as well (meaning to deal with something directly). An example for 'to put one's shoulders back' might be, "Don't listen to criticism -- stand tall, put your shoulders back and tell yourself 'You got this!'" Even though the parent's criticism/advice is literal, it is also suggestive of a certain attitude he is telling his child to take. I believe he's telling him to take a confident, assertive stance both physically and at heart. It's as if he's saying,"Be a man!" to a little boy.